# Remove Google Play Service on Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-api, google-play-services

I'm developing an application that will use Google Drive, and part of setting that up is seeing if the Google Services API is up to date/active. I want to test and make sure the dialog works as intended, but I'd rather not test with my phone, and attempting to remove Google Play Services on an Emulator results in the following error in the logs:

```
2018-12-22 14:54:22.390 13934-15195/? E/SystemServiceRegistry: No service published for: wifip2p
    android.os.ServiceManager$ServiceNotFoundException: No service published for: wifip2p
        at android.os.ServiceManager.getServiceOrThrow(ServiceManager.java:75)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistry$49.createService(SystemServiceRegistry.java:569)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistry$49.createService(SystemServiceRegistry.java:567)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistry$StaticServiceFetcher.getService(SystemServiceRegistry.java:987)
        at android.app.SystemServiceRegistry.getSystemService(SystemServiceRegistry.java:914)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:1667)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:171)
        at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5925)
        at com.android.settings.wfd.WifiDisplaySettings.isAvailable(WifiDisplaySettings.java:216)
        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.doUpdateTilesList(SettingsActivity.java:845)
        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.android.settings.SettingsActivity$5.run(SettingsActivity.java:747)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2018-12-22 14:54:22.462 1639-1656/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2018-12-22 14:54:22.472 1639-1656/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2018-12-22 14:54:22.476 1639-1656/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
```

How to I properly disable/uninstall this service for testing, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to set up a second emulator image, one that does not have Play Services in it in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare It is that simple.  Be advised, an emulator with Google Play is recommended.  On the other hand, I believe this error is because of some Google Play dependency defined inside the app.

Comment: There will be a Google Play dependency in the application, however this error is from the emulator OS itself, not my app. Specifically when I try to "Uninstall Updates" from the application info screen, as advised by one of the sources I found when trying to remove the service.

@CommonsWare, what would you advise for creating a second emulator image?

Comment: When you create the emulator AVD, choose a target that does not mention "Google". For example, choose "Android 9.0", not "Android 9.0 (Google APIs)" or "Android 9.0 (Google Play)".